# Why is she throwing water on the ground?

Tags: culture, soul-eater

So if seen this happen in a few anime's before, but never really understood why it happens.

A character with a wooden spoon like object and a bucket of water throws water on the ground during summer.  Why are they doing this?

[image]

Comment: Oh wow lol, I paused a bit to early... They actually explained it right after this scene. If somebody wants to type out the answer feel free to :)

Comment: Just FYI, this is Soul Eater Not!

Comment: @user1306322 yh i know. But the soul eater tag is ment for both series ^^

Comment: it's a common practice in some country to make dust disappear, especially in summer when there's a lot of dust on the street, when vehicle came, it will make the dust flies by its wind so we throw water on street to reduce the dust. But it can be dangerous since it can make the street become more slippery

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Never heard of the practice before. Might be because I life in a country where it rains allot... all year long....

Comment: @Dimitrimx in my country, it not called summer anymore, it's a drought. No rain for months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [Uchimizu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchimizu).

People do this to cool the street and as an effect - cools the surrounding area and reduces the amount of dust that flies around.

In recent times there has been a push for people to use recycled water instead to reduce waste.

The ladle and bucket are traditional, and can be replaced by hoses, buckets or any handy implement. Ladles and buckets are used exclusively at Uchimizu festivals though.

[Uchimizu.jp](http://www.uchimizu.jp/language/en/) provides a handy how-to guide for the activity:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Further reading :)](http://www.axiommagazine.jp/2012/06/25/keeping-cool-101-uchimizu/)

Comment: Now to find out if this actually works, we might need to ask on Physics.SE…

Comment: never thought there's actually a name for this kind of activity...

Comment: @user1306322 have you asked this to Physics.SE? if so please link me the question, thank you.

Comment: @AsshO.Le posted http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114869/does-uchimizu-watering-streets-in-summer-help-reduce-temperature-in-an-area

Comment: the old people in my country did this too.

i guess its not japanese habit only

Comment: the further reading link looks like it's been domain squatted and redirects to a porn site. Recommend removing the link